# Must i any pre encode binary data to send it as base64 on ios?

Tags: php, ios, iphone, ios7, base64

I send to the server video (. mov)  previously devide file to chunks. Every chunk i encode base64 and send it in HTTP POST. PHP-server decode base64 string with standard decoder. Size of chunk before send is more big, then decoded on server. Question: must i additionally somehow encode my binary data before encode it to base64?

There is my code:

```
// ...

NSFileHandle* file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
if( file )
{
     [file seekToFileOffset:[[XDRUtils toNumber:[obj valueForKey:@"offset"]] longLongValue]];
      NSData* data = [file readDataOfLength:xkChunckSize];
      [file closeFile];

       NSString* base64 = [data toBase64String];

       [post setObject: base64 forKey: @"record_segment_content"];

}

// send to server
// ...

// Category for base64 en
@implementation NSData (XDRBase64)

-(NSString*)toBase64String
{
    NSString *string;

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(base64EncodedStringWithOptions:)])
    {
        string = [self base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];  // iOS 7+
    }
    else
    {
        string = [self base64Encoding];                              // pre iOS7
    }

    return string;
}

// ...

@end
```

**Update:**

Problem solved. On php-server we replace all space character to the '+' in base64-string before decode.

Comment: What do you mean by "additionally encode"? For security? For compression? Otherwise it seems perfectly fine to me like that already.

Comment: How are you testing the size of data, before and after encoding, on the client and server?

Comment: Wain, I know length of chunk (in bytes) before encoding. And I see length of chunk(in bytes) after server decoded it. len_before > len_after

Comment: Romain, I guess that the server can wait for a string in a particular encoding. Such UTF8 or any other